# Processing regular expression matches before replacing

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, transform

I'm looking for applications and programming language constructs to search for a regular expression pattern, transform the match in some way and then replace it. A very simple example: Transforming "myCamelCasedString" to "my_camel_cased_string".

In Ruby it's easy and concise:

```
 s = "myCamelCasedString".gsub(/[A-Z]/) { |m| "_" + m.downcase }
```

In PHP it's longer, but also possible

```
  preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', 
     // Using PHP 5.3 anonymous function as callback
     function($m) { return "_" . strtolower($m[0]); }, 
    "myCamelCasedString");
```

The text editor jEdit also supports this through a "Beanshell snippet" but I always have to look up how to do it. So - how would I do this in other languages and is there a dedicated application/editor that lets me do this (together with a handy reference of possible transformations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ruby is the dedicated application you're looking for:

The data:

```
some other text
myCamelCasedString
here is yetAnotherCamelCasedString
```

The scriptlet:

```
$ ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/[A-Z]/) { |m| "_" + m.downcase }' <input
some other text
my_camel_cased_string
here is yet_another_camel_cased_string
```

The magic sauce is the "-p" switch.  It wraps the code provided with the "-e" switch in "while gets (); ... ; print $_ end".  '$_' is a Perlish variable which holds the most recently read line.

Comment: I recently read the book "Ruby for Sysadmins" and found some amazing one-liners using the -pe flag. There are other flags that make the ruby interpreter act like `awk`. Awesome stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
$str =~ s/([A-Z])/'_'.lc$1/eg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I want this question answered in as many programming languages as possible, here is the **JavaScript** solution:

```
s = "myCamelCasedString".replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(s) { 
  return '_'+s.toLowerCase();
});
```

See the [documentation from MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for details on the function parameters. You get submatches and the match offset as additional parameters.

---

Here is the **Python** solution:

```
import re
re.sub(r"[A-Z]", lambda s: "_" + s.group(0).lower(), "myCamelCasedString")
```